# Google Cloud App Engine Flexbile quota error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, quota, app-engine-flexible

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: CPUS (quota: 
0, used: 0 + needed: 4).
```

Trying to deploy nodejs application in **App Engine** flexible environment in a new google cloud project using **gcloud**.

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 3.5
  disk_size_gb: 20
network:
  name: default
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
```

For some reason i am unable to successfully deploy in app engine flexible environment.

Comment: What is the region of your App Engine?

Comment: asia-south1 is my app engine locationId @JohnMichaelG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the Free Trial, this a known issue or the stock-out issue in that region(asia-south). Here are my recommendations:

1. Try to add this in app.yaml and deploy:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 7
```

2. Run or deploy on App Engine Standard.
3. Change the region of your App Engine. Please note, you cannot change your App Engine region, you will need to create a new project and set the other region **except** `asia-south`.
4. Run or deploy the app on a different [product](https://cloud.google.com/products).
5. Google Cloud is now offer a feature called reservations that guarantees Google Cloud capacity, see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for details on how to use this feature.
6. Create a Quota Request for CPU.

Comment: I am able to deploy in app engine standard.